# Headers set in a function call within a while loop only proceed once

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I have a call from PHP to a function, but it stops after the first run.

```
while ($rowfight = $resultfights->fetch_assoc()) {
    // ..
    merge($file1, $file2, $filename_result, $rowfight['team1Name'], $rowfight['team2Name'], $rowfight['description'], '' );
    // ..
}

function merge($filename_x, $filename_y, $filename_result, $team1, $team2, $battle, $winner ) {
    // Do some stuff with image here
    // ..
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename_result));
    imagepng($image);
    // ..
}
```

It downloads the first `.png` image, and then stops.

What to do?
(I know it's something with the headers but I can't find out what)

Comment: You cannot add headers once output has been generated, unless you use output buffering.

Comment: I did try
ob_start(merge(...));
ob_end_flush
With same result

Comment: In addition, what exactly do you think will happen if you send multiple similar headers and multiple PNG streams in a single HTTP response?

Comment: Well - Can't say :-)
I have X rows and for each of them I need to create a PNG that will downloade to my harddrive.
What you say, is, that I can't do it?

Comment: No, HTTP was designed to handle a single file per request. What you *could* do is combine all the PNG images into a single ZIP-file and offer that ZIP for download.

Comment: OK - Thank you.
Then I think I just put it in a folder on the server and dowloade by ftp. 
As it is me (and just me) that will be using this feature

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

I used the Dropbox api, and then I have files on my hd, shortly after creation.

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers)